.readthedocs.yaml : needs to stop after commands done
This is my .readthedocs.yaml script:
# Required
version: 2

# Set the version of Python and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.12"
  apt_packages:
    - cmake
    - gfortran
    - gcc
    - g++
    - git
  jobs:
    pre_install:
      - echo "in build - jobs - pre_install:"
      - echo "READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT=$READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT "
      - pwd; ls -lt 
      - cmake --version
      - git --version
      - python -V
      - pip install "sphinx<7.0.0" sphinx_rtd_theme sphinxcontrib-bibtex
      - sphinx-build  --version
      - git submodule update --init --recursive
      - ./setup $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT
      - pwd
      - ls -lt
      - cd $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/; pwd; ls -lt; make html; pwd; ls -lt; ls -lt html/ ; exit $?
      - exit 0

After running all the "pre_install" commands I want to end the yaml script, but the script continues with some unwanted defaults commands  (like python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip setuptools ,  python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir sphinx ,  cat doc/conf.py ... ) and crashes.
Any help please on how completely stop the yaml script running ?
(PS: Here is the whole yaml run, https://readthedocs.org/projects/dirac-fork/builds/26199242/ , with unwanted extra steps)

Maybe use post_install or post_build instead? https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-customization.html
